# How to wait for Redis cache to cache the information

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data, spring-cache

I am using spring-data-redis and trying to have a junit with which, I can test my Caching logic. The test case sporadically works. I guess if the caching logic completes before the invocation of the second method call then it works else it fails. If some has faced a similar issue, I will like to understand how they made it work. As of now, I am using thread.sleep() but looking for an alternative.

```
  @Test
  public void getUserById() {
  User user = new User("name", "1234");
when(userRepository.findbyId("1234")).thenReturn(Optional.ofNullable(user));
  // first method call
  User user1 = userService.findbyId("1234");

  assertThat(user.getName()).isEqualTo(user1.getName());
  assertThat(user.getId).isEqualTo(user1.getId());

  // sleeping the thread so to provide caching aspect sufficient time 
  // to cache the information
  try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  // second method call, expecting cache to work.
  userCache = userService.findbyId("1234");
  verify(userRepository, never()).findbyId("1234");
  assertThat(user.getName()).isEqualTo(userCache.getName());
  assertThat(user.getId).isEqualTo(userCache.getId());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual issue was not with the Thread wait time. For Redis cache to work a separate thread need to be spanned. For my service test, I tested it via a separated test case.

```
 @Test
 public void getUserById() {
   User user = new User("name", "1234");
   when(userRepository.findbyId("1234")).thenReturn(Optional.ofNullable(user));
    // first method call
   User user1 = userService.findbyId("1234");
   assertThat(user.getName()).isEqualTo(user1.getName());
   assertThat(user.getId).isEqualTo(user1.getId());
 }
 //ensure this test case is executed after getUserById. I used 
 //@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
 @Test
 public void getUserById_cache() {
   User user1 = userService.findbyId("1234");
   Mockito.verify(userRepository, never()).findbyId("1234")
   assertThat(user.getName()).isEqualTo(user1.getName());
   assertThat(user.getId).isEqualTo(user1.getId());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Runtime issues while waiting a short amount of time a really common in a distributed system. To remedy the need of waiting too long for a test assertion, there is a little tool called [Awaitility](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility).

With this you can basically do a much cleverer wait by querying an assertion multiple times, in certain intervals until a given timeout was reached (…and much more).

Regarding your example, try this:

```
        Awaitility.await()
                .pollInterval(new Duration(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                .atMost(new Duration(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                .untilAsserted(() -> 
                    User user1 = userService.findbyId("1234");
                    assertThat(user1.getName()).isEqualTo(user.getName());
```

Regarding the other part of your question, in an integration test you could actually perform some kind of prewarming of your `Redis` instance or if you have a containerized integration test (e. g. Docker) you could fire some first requests on it or [wait for a certain condition](http://dmp.fabric8.io/#start-wait) before starting with your tests.